# How to ensure a stolen MacBook Pro Retina is useless to a thief?

Tags: filevault, find-my-mac, security

(There are similar questions to this, but they all are old, like OS X Snow Leopard old. This is for Catalina era.)

I carry my MacBook Pro on me almost always when I go places. I keep it in my backpack. While the threat of it being stolen doesn't loom too badly where I live, and I don't ever let it out of my reach, I still want to make sure that my Mac is useless to a thief if it is stolen.

Currently, I have FileVault 2 full-disk encryption enabled, as well as Find My Mac enabled to the full extent and I have a password set on the EFI to prevent booting from external volumes.

How effective would this be, and is there anything I could do additionally to ensure they can't bypass these measures to use or sell the machine?

Comment: What generation (i.e. model release year/season) of MacBook Pro Retina is it? The hardware security has changed a few times over the years. (There's a big list of MBP models [here](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html).)

Comment: @GordonDavisson The model I'm wondering about is a Late-2013, BTO 2.6 GHz with Dual Graphics.

Answer (score 2):

The security you’ve enabled probably won’t deter the theft of your laptop.  Most criminals who get the opportunity to snatch a laptop will take it no matter how useless you can make it with encryption and firmware locks.

Why?

- Ignorance of the criminal.  No matter how much Apple advertises it, the common thief won’t know until they get it back home only to find they got a brick.  Then it will probably become a frizbee.
- Salvage value.  Although useless as a computer, the machine becomes a “donor” for the parts including the screen, trackpad, keyboard etc.  even the logic board can supply someone with a ton of components to be used in logic board repair

Your strategy should be *data protection*, ensuring that no matter where your computer ends up, you have quick, secure access to your work product.  Enabling remote wipe is invaluable in making sure your data stays secure.

I would also look at insurance coverage for that expensive device.  Many credit cards cover theft.  There are also 3rd party insurance coverage from companies like [Safeware](https://www.safeware.com/)

Comment: And a criminal who is not ignorant can open it, remove the drive, erase it and re-install.  If it doesn't have Monterey or firmware password, they can erase and re-install from the recovery partition.  So it's not really useless as a computer.  Could even replace the drive with a new one.

Comment: If a criminal is smart enough, they'll power up somewhere with no Wifi and turn WiFi off to disable "Find My" and remote wipe possibilities.